# Drag legend out of Highchart

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts, drag-and-drop

I have a bunch of series represented as button outside of the chart which are draggable. When ever I drag these onto the line chart I add that serie with correct values. This part is working.

I wan't the similar workflow when I want to remove series from the chart. The legend item is probably the best item to drag off the chart, however - I have major issues with making the legend draggable with the native HTML5 drag and drop API.

I use HTML-legend and append the correct HTML attributes to it, without luck. Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5rZ65/1/).

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        },
        legend: {
            useHTML: true
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
        }]
    });
$('div .highcharts-legend-item span')
    .attr('draggable', 'true')
    .attr('ondragstart', 'dragChartLegend(event)');
});

function dragChartLegend(event) {
    console.log(event);
}
```

I'm not quite sure what's causing the issue - but I belive it's something Highcharts does - as just a raw copy and paste of the legend somewhere else on the site works fine.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Unforunately in this way it is not possible, because the symbol will not move (it is not html element, but svg). You can try to adapt this plugin: 
http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/32/draggable-legend-box

Comment: Hello Sebastian and thanks for your reply. From the generated code it looks like the useHTML flag renders the legend as HTML elements (divs) outside of the chart (at least outside of the svg tag). Can you please comment further on this?

I have looked at the movable legend plugin, but unfortunately the legend is rendered as svg which you can't drag out of the canvas.

Comment: Honestly, you can try to move svg elements, but I have no soltuion for it.